# Customrenderer for JTable is getting called multiple times

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to color certain rows in JTable based on its value. But my `customrenderer` is getting called infinite times and the whole table is getting colored instead of certain rows.

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,int row, int column) 
{
    Component c = render.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
    String flag = (String)model.getValueAt(row, 0);

    if(flag.equalsIgnoreCase("java"))
    {

        c.setBackground(new Color(0xE8F2FE)); //light blue
    }

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far.

Comment: Did you mean `super.getTableCellRendererComponent()`?

Comment: yes. I mean super.getTableCellRendererComponent()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same renderer is used for all cells. Once you change the background of the renderer that background is used for all the cells.

So you need an "else condition" to set the background to the default color. Something like:

```
else
   c.setBackground( table.getBackground() );
```

You can also check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for an alternative approach to highlighting a rows background which can be simpler especially when different types of data are found in each column.